# How to get the Normal line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My book proposed to me to find the the Normal lines to the curve that pass through the origin.The answer must be the intersection points between them.

The curve: $\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$

My first idea is to get the derivative: $f'(x) = $ $\frac{-4x}{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}$, then get the perpendicular of $f'(x)$, resulting in 
$M = \dfrac{-1}{f'(x)}$ = $\dfrac{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}{4x}$.

The segment that pass through the origin with the angular coeficient $M$ is:

$g(x) = M * (x - x0) + y0$; to $x0$ = 0 and $y0$ = 0.

So, $g(x) = \dfrac{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}{4}$

Finally to get the common points between $g(x)$ and $f(x)$, I have the equality: $f(x) = g(x)$.

$\dfrac{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}{4}$ = $\dfrac{2}{x^2 + 1}$

Resulting in two real solutions: $x = -1$ and $x = 1$ and another four complex roots. If you look carefully, we can see a "hidden" solution at x = 0.

Is it the right way to procced to get the points !?

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle x=\tan\theta, y=\frac2{1+x^2}=2\cos^2\theta$

So, $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}=-4\tan\theta\cos^4\theta=-4\sin\theta\cos^3\theta$

So, the equation of the normal at $(\tan\theta,2\cos^2\theta)$

$$\frac{y-2\cos^2\theta}{x-\tan\theta}=-\frac1{-4\sin\theta\cos^3\theta}$$

$$\implies(y-2\cos^2\theta)4\sin\theta\cos^4\theta=x-\sin\theta \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Now as the normal passes through the origin, set $x=y=0$ to find the required values of $\theta$

$$\implies(0-2\cos^2\theta)4\sin\theta\cos^4\theta=0-\sin\theta\iff\sin\theta(8\cos^6\theta-1)=0$$

If $\displaystyle\sin\theta=0\implies\cos^2\theta=1, (1)$ becomes $\displaystyle y-2=x$

If $\displaystyle8\cos^6\theta-1=0,$ the only real value of $\displaystyle\cos^2\theta$ is $\displaystyle\frac12\implies\sin\theta=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$

Put the values of  $\displaystyle\cos^2\theta,\sin\theta$ in $(1)$

Comment: Sorry lab, I'm learning about basic calculus.
I didn't understand your explanation, could you be more specific ?

Comment: @mastergoo, Have you heard of parametric equation ?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your signs: $ f'(x) = \frac{-4x}{x^4 +2x^2 +1} $. Otherwise your approach seems good to me. I hope you understand why you are taking the negative reciprocal of the derivative and why you are setting $ g(x) $ equal to $ f(x) $.

Comment: Wow. It is true.

Comment: I committed a mistake, I eddited the right way now.

Comment: I understand fine, but I cant understand the four complex roots of the solution. The real solution in x = 1, x = -1 and x = 0.

Comment: I am not so sure $ x = 0 $ is a root. Check that root again. As to find the other roots, try to divide the polynomial you are solving by linear factors which correspond to the roots you have found: $ x = 1$ and $x = -1$.

Comment: When x = 0, it lies on the top of the function, angular coefficient is = 0, we have p(0,2), the normal is y = 0.

Comment: How can I modify $g(x)% ?

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself. However, to make your function $ g(x) $ more clear, you should write it as $ g(x) = M*x $ instead of canceling the $ x $ out with that in the denominator in $ M $.

Comment: Sure, to make it clear.

Comment: It is a good thing you found the root $ x = 0 $. It can't be found by solving the equation you found, but this "hidden" root results from the fact that the derivative is 0 at this point.

Comment: Yes, it is a hidden solution hahahahah.

Comment: Do you understand how to find the complex solutions now?

Comment: I have no idea how to find then, I saw it because the wolfram give me the roots from g(x) = f(x).

Comment: If you eliminate the fractions from the equation you got, what do you get?

Comment: x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 = 2 ?

Comment: No, I mean if you multiply each side by the LCM of the denominators so that we don't have to deal with fractions anymore, what do we yield (we want to change this equation into something easier to solve, because fractions aren't easy to deal with).

Comment: (x+1)(x-1)(x^4+4x^2+7))/((x^2+1)*4), Hahahah now I see. Really easy. @pidude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15458/discussion-between-pidude-and-mastergoo).